# "If it was not cold, I would like more" -- conditional

Tags: conditionals

Now I'm having hard time on something.

I ate something yesterday and it was cold. Now grammatically, it must be

**If it was not cold, I would like it more.**

But I feel like it does not sound right, just because of 'like'. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two other ways of saying what you want said. The first point to consider, however, is that you ate whatever **IT** was yesterday, so your sentence has to be in the past tense.

> If it **had not been** cold, I would have **liked** it more.  [This is educated English.]
>
> **Had it not been** cold, I would have **liked** it more. [This is formal English. Not generally used when speaking because it's normally too formal, but if you're speaking to someone wearing a tuxedo or a morning coat, it's perfectly appropriate. It's also appropriate for formal writing, but I doubt that there are many contexts in which such formality is called for.]

Your feeling that your sentence is grammatically incorrect because of *like* is a proper feeling, because *like* should be ***liked***.

Comment: what about the first part? What is the difference between,'if it were not cold' vs 'if it had not been cold'

Comment: 'If it were not cold' is present subjunctive & describes an unreal condition at the moment: It **is** cold, so I **don't** like it now. 'If it had not been cold' is past subjunctive & describes an unreal condition in the past (yesterday): It **was** cold, so id **didn't** like it. This is what, it seems to me, your sentence wants to say, that **you would have liked it better yesterday had it not been so cold**.

Comment: @Barrie: It's one of those damned numbered conditionals that I never learned but have been calling a "subjunctive" all my life because that's what I was taught unreal conditions were: subjunctive mood. I know I promised not to use that word again, but I don't know what 1st, 2nd, & 3rd conditionals correspond to. Sorry about the terminological problem. But, to be perfectly native-speakerish about it, you know what I mean. :-)

Comment: Comment edited. Here it is again.There must be a transatlantic difference here. _If it had not been cold_ is, to me, simply the past tense of _have_, followed by _been_, followed by the past participle of the main verb. The construction is no different from the first clause in _It had not been cold that week, so we had been able to go out a little._ Where’s the subjunctive?

Comment: _If it had not been cold, I would have liked it more_ is the Third Conditional, for those who care about such things.

Comment: @Barrie: "It had not been cold that week" and "If it had not been cold (that week)" are not at all the same. One is a description of reality and the other is an unreal past conditional (It was cold that week) with a Scarlet Number (1, 2, or 3, signifying whatever) hanging on its Hester Prynne-like robin redbreast. Well, there you go: 3rd conditional, a vacuous piece of nomenclature if ever I've seen one. Tells me nothing about unreal past condition. Terminology explains nothing.

Comment: @BillFranke 100% agreed with you on the uselessness of terminology. Don’t worry about these so-called “numbered” conditionals. They’re just an ESL-crutch. They don’t map well to actual usage: it’s been shown that many other forms are used by native speakers. The important thing is whether we are hypothesizing  about a past event (*if it had been*), or whether we are hypothesizing a “non-past” event (*if it were*). I would avoid getting drawn into arguments about labels of the various inflectional bits of those and instead focus on the two oppositional and contrasting cases of past vs non-past.

Comment: @tchrist: I think my answer hits all the necessary grammatical points. Did I miss anything, do you think?

Comment: Maybe, but the constructions are identical, and no linguist I know of would call it subjunctive. If we exclude formulaic subjunctives and irrealis _were_, then the only form the subjunctive ever takes is the plain form of the verb, as in, for example, _They suggested that he leave_.

Comment: I might have omitted the inversion case with the implied *if*, which is formal and maybe even literary or poetic, even though it sounds nice enough. I just make a past–present distinction myself.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Once again, you are talking about inflectional morphology of individual words. That is of little practical use here, given that most foreign-language instruction includes compound verb forms. Indeed, you cannot teach without those. The [standard instructional model](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/be.html) talks about these things from a different level, one of practical use to the student. It sounds like Bill’s coming from that point of view, not from the one that considers nothing but individual words in synchronically viewed inflections, which appears to be yours.

Comment: @tchrist. As I suggested, the approach may be different on each side of the Atlantic. Either way, the subjunctive isn't worth spending much time on, given its rarity.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a question of subjunctive verb moods. When deciding to use 'were' vs. 'was' (verb for 'to be') you need to think about the mood you're trying to communicate. In your example, you're talking about something that isn't true in a wishful tone: the food was too cold for your liking, ie. you wish it had been warmer.

Therefore 'were' is the correct subjunctive because were is used to communicate a wish for something.

> "I wish I were more perceptive."

Same thing applies to your case.

> "If it weren't so cold, I'd like it more."

is the correct way to phrase it.

You use 'was' when talking about something certain, factual, or likely.

> "I was sick last week"
>
> "Bill was going to come over, but he couldn't make it."

You can also rephrase your sentence to use 'was' - can you see why, in this example, 'was' is correct? (hint: 'was' = factual, ie. something that has happened already)

> "The dish was cold, so I didn't like it"

Comment: what about second part, should not it be ' If it were not cold, I would have liked it more'?

Comment: @EmmetB  It depends on when you say it. Yesterday, at the time when you were eating it, you said: "If it weren't so cold I'd like it more."  Today, looking back, you say "If it hadn't been so cold I'd have liked it more." (In both cases, *I'd* = *I would*).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn’t sound right because if it is something that you are experiencing in the present, something you are eating right now, then it should be more like this:

> - If it weren’t so cold, I’d like it more. (*spoken*)
> - If it were not so cold, I would like it more. (*uncontracted*)

Whereas if it is something that has already occurred, something that we ate yesterday or last week or whatnot, then it should be more like this:

> - If it hadn’t been so cold, I’d’ve liked it more. (*spoken*)
> - If it had not been so cold, I would have liked it more. (*uncontracted*)